# How to create a facebook app without much knowledge of PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to SUGGEST, or CREATE an app, and I don't have any knowledge of facebook app creation... I've looked up on tutorials, but facebook's API might change or has changed by the date of those tutorials...

So I thought I'll ask on here, after searching for a facebook developer's support, I was redirected to here.

**My question**: What is the best way to create a basic app, as per my requirements (below)..?

**My Suggestion/Requirements**: I wrote this [tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/693252/how-to-post-my-currently-playing-song-to-my-website) on superuser, which lets you display your current playing track as an updated div on your html based website. I'm trying to create a facebook app that posts these track info updates to the right side of the facebook home panel (above the chat column). Like Spotify! Or SoundCloud...

**My Problem**: I don't know where to start? I don't have much knowledge of scripting and according to me, it should be quite simple in PHP/MYSQL/Javascript/ ... but don't know how facebook would handle the html file from where the `<div>` data could be collected. I think jquery would solve that, but this can also be done via PHP/MYSQL.

It should be simple, so I'm also suggesting this as an idea for anyone willing to create this app on facebook? And if you create it, please do keep it open source project or a tutorial for it, so that if at any time you close the app, it can still be replicated. I cannot create it but am willing to, but don't know how to...

I'm asking this here because facebook doesn't appear to have a forum based posts for this apart from [the developers group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/). I've joined the facebook developers group, but haven't yet been allowed to post anything, as the join request is pending.

That's mostly all. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Its a very broad question actually. You gotta try something first then ask for the specific problem. The thing you are trying to do is quite simple and straight away. Start learning basics from here: http://developers.facebook.com/ Then learn about open graph stories. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any IRC for facebook developers?

Comment: IRC = [Internet Relay Chat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) ... It's like a chat room where you can chat on any topic... I use Xchat on Windows & Linux for IRC, there are portable versions available for both.

Comment: Found an IRC Channel on [fbdevwiki](http://fbdevwiki.com/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=irc)

Answer (score 1):

Start with registering  your application on Facebook .It will give you some token and keys.
Now you can follow any tutorial online to create application on fb.

Comment: The [URL](http://apps.new.facebook.com/) on this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-first-facebook-app--net-471) has just been blocked by my google chrome... Could you suggest a recent tutorial?

Comment: @mk117 dont follow any 3rd party tutorials, the official docs are good enough!

Comment: ok. Thanks! I downloaded some [video tutorials](http://www.lynda.com/Facebook-tutorials/Building-Facebook-Applications-PHP-MySQL/107060-2.html) from Lynda.com ... could you suggest which of these videos would be necessary for viewing? Or should I watch them all?

Comment: @mk117 you should follow complete tutorial it will give you complete idea of things